# Open new tab with POST method

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new tab and send data to it in a POST request from my chrome extension. I could use a GET request, but the data I am going to send could be arbitrarily long, and I want to JSON encode it(which also means I cannot use forms). I've only found two questions on SO about this, but both of them are talking about using a form, which is not desirable.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to request further input from the user before I do what I do with the data. I am totally lost here and have no idea how to do this, hence I can not add any code samples I've tried.

If I cannot do this with a URL, I could inject a script into the page and have a popup, but that is something of a last resort.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: What's your goal? Submitting a POST request with a JSON payload, and having the result displayed in a tab by the browser, such that the displayed URL is the requested URL and refreshing the page causes the same request to be submitted? That is not possible.

Comment: In theory you could open an extension page in the new tab which creates a form and submits it. It could be a little complex getting the data to the extension page but it would probably work.

Comment: @RobW The refreshing part is not required, just sending a JSON payload in a POST request would be enough.

Comment: @abraham Yes, I could do that, but that is only something I'd do if nothing else works.

Comment: @NikBarres Then you'd use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` (from the extension's background page or from a tab where you'd like to display the result) and put the response in the tab.

Comment: How exactly would I put the response from `XMLHttpRequest` in a tab? I've never seen that before.